# Easiest way to remove GBs of unwanted history from a mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

When I started using Mercurial, I stored all of my "research & resources" within the repo, which included GBs of videos. These large files accumulated over time, and are tracked across changesets.

I recently "removed" these folders from the repo, because I would like to open-source the project, and these are simply personal resources that only weigh down the repository.

However, despite moving these resources out of the repo, all of the videos are still stored within the history. This makes it painfully slow to clone the repo to a server, and seemingly impossible to push it to BitBucket.

Am I correct in thinking that it would be easiest to make a backup of the current repo, `hg init` a new one with only the core project files (starting fresh with the version history), and chalk this up as a fun learning experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a completely new repository is of course possible. However the history can be interesting as well. You can use `hg convert` on the old repository, and exclude the files which you do not want to be part of the new repository in that process. You could then share the new lean repository thus created.

```
hg convert --filemap FILEMAP old-repo new-repo
```

where `FILEMAP` is a file which contains the rules for conversion, e.g.

```
exclude path/to/largefiles
```

Checkout `hg help convert` as well. The old and the new repository will be similarily unrelated as would be a new repository created by a simple `hg init`, though. But you have retained the part of history and files which you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you. How would I go about excluding the path/to/largefiles if I have moved and renamed these folders a handful of times? Should I exclude every possible path that these files have resided at during the history of the repo?

Comment: I haven't tested myself, but probably yes. Check the previous names by getting the history of one (or several) of the files: `hg log --follow FILENAME`

Comment: Lastly, whilst I've got you, should I backup old-repo, or does `hg convert` leave old-repo unaffected? Thanks again.

Comment: Backups never hurt. But `convert` is like `clone` an action which doesn't touch the original repo